# Kotlin NullPointerException occurrence

Tags: nullpointerexception, kotlin

I'm new to [[image]kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin), I'm confused the situation at below when I starting to [Null Safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html).

> There's some data inconsistency with regard to initialization (an uninitialized this available in a constructor is used somewhere).

Could anyone describe the situation more in detailed?

Comment: 5 seconds of Googling revealed this: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/nre-from-an-uninitialized-this-in-constructor/1966

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth thanks first, I'm from China, I'm sorry I can't open your link. could you write down in the answer, sir?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example adapted from a [Kotlin discussion on exactly this](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/nre-from-an-uninitialized-this-in-constructor/1966):

```
class Foo {
    val c: String          // Non-nullable

    init {
        bar()
        c = ""             // Initialised for the first time here
    }

    fun bar() {
        println(c.length)  // Oh dear
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Foo()
}
```

Comment: thanks very much,sir. I understand it immediately by your example.